# Simple AJAX code that refreshes every x seconds?

Tags: ajax

I read that `admin-ajax.php` sends request every 15 seconds.

Knowing that, is there a simple code that I could use to take advantage of that?

What I mean by that, let's say I have a text that is changing.

But to see the changes, I need to refresh the page every time.

Which I don't want.

Instead I want to wrap that code around the AJAX:

```
<ajax code updates every 15 second>

My code goes here

</ajax code updates every 15 second>
```

to be updated in a real time.

That's  a very rough example, just to get the point.

Is there any simple way to do that?

I wish Wordpress had a simple code that you put your code and it would update in real time.

Any help would be appreciated.

I want to refresh the code in the `single.php` template.

**UPDATE:** Sorted with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
        $('#Status').load('/myphpfile.php');
    }, 20000); // refresh every 20 seconds
</script>
<body>
    <div id="Status"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What you're describing in your first sentence is the [Heartbeat API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/heartbeat-api/), but that's typically just for admin use. On the front end you would need to implement the timer in JavaScript, which is unrelated to WordPress. Then inside that timer you'd send an AJAX request like normal.

Comment: You can use HeartBeat API on the front-end also.